# Excel - Search & Replace - Multiple placeholder

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

is it possible to set a certain sequence of placeholders in Excels "Search & Replace Function" ?

I got data like:

- **aaa-bbb**
- aaaaaa-bbb
- **aaaa-bbbbbb**

and I only want to manipulate data that is less than 4 characters before the hyphen (the bold ones)

The placeholder in Excel is the ?-Operator so i tried 4 consecutive question marks ("**????-***), but it counts as 1 i guess.

Is this  at all possible with Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can't do it with core Excel functionality.

I use free [Excel RegEx Find/Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php), it has a custom find / replace dialog where you can use regular expressions.

You can look for `^\w{0,3}-`

In below picture it finds first and last values:

[image]